# rpy2 error loading R package "rugarch" in Python

Tags: r, rpy2

I tried to use rpy2 to load library **rugarch** but encountered the following error. It seems to have something to do with the dependency **multicool**. Checked in R both libaries can be loaded without errors. Could anyone help look into it? Thanks a lot!

```
from rpy2.robjects import r
r("""library(rugarch)""")

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-07367cb75221>", line 1, in <module>
    r("""library(rugarch)""")

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2-2.9.0-py3.6-win-amd64.egg\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 352, in __call__
    res = self.eval(p)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2-2.9.0-py3.6-win-amd64.egg\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 178, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2-2.9.0-py3.6-win-amd64.egg\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 106, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)

RRuntimeError: Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rugarch' in .doLoadActions(where, attach):
 error in load action .__A__.1 for package multicool: loadModule(module = "Multicool", what = TRUE, env = ns, loadNow = TRUE): Unable to load module "Multicool": negative length vectors are not allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

RR and Python (then calling R through rpy2) are almost certainly run in different environments. As result`Multicool` can be loaded in the former but not in the latter.

(Note: rpy2 is not officially supported on Windows)